# aruco_detect, can't access fiducial_id

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm trying to acces the fiducial_id in aruco_detect, but I get this error message:

```
error: ‘fiducial_msgs::FiducialTransformArray_<std::allocator<void> >::_transforms_type’ {aka ‘class std::vector<fiducial_msgs::FiducialTransform_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<fiducial_msgs::FiducialTransform_<std::allocator<void> > > >’} has no member named ‘fiducial_id’
   25 |     h.transforms.fiducial_id;
```

I'm not sure why it's saying this, because it should be there according to this:

```
>rosmsg info fiducial_msgs/FiducialTransformArray 
std_msgs/Header header
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
int32 image_seq
fiducial_msgs/FiducialTransform[] transforms
  int32 fiducial_id
  geometry_msgs/Transform transform
    geometry_msgs/Vector3 translation
      float64 x
      float64 y
      float64 z
    geometry_msgs/Quaternion rotation
      float64 x
      float64 y
      float64 z
      float64 w
  float64 image_error
  float64 object_error
  float64 fiducial_area
```

This how where I'm trying to access it:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "fiducial_msgs/FiducialTransformArray.h"
using namespace std;


void counterCallback(const fiducial_msgs::FiducialTransformArray::ConstPtr msg){

    int update_time;
    ROS_INFO("Hello");
   
}

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    ros::init(argc,argv,"marker_detect");/*Initialiserer node med navn*/
    ros::NodeHandle n;

    ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe<fiducial_msgs::FiducialTransformArray>("fiducial_transforms",10,counterCallback);
    fiducial_msgs::FiducialTransformArray h;
    h.transforms.fiducial_id;

    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387311/aruco_detect,-can%27t-access-fiducial_id/) by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2021-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the name implies, `fiducial_msgs::FiducialTransformArray` is an array (or list).

You cannot access the field of a single element without first indexing into the array.

`h.transforms.fiducial_id` does indeed not exist.

`h.transforms[i].fiducial_id`, where `i ∈ ℕ`, does exist. It would mean you're accessing the `fiducial_id` field of the `i`-th element in `h.transforms`.

For a related question (but with `rospy`), see #q359824.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on 2021-09-24**:
Oh, thank you. That explains it!